# $\Omega \subset Z\setminus bZ $ where $Z$ is integer set and $a,b, \epsilon Z$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

for $gcd(a,b)=1$ uppose a set $\Omega$={ x:$ax+b$ is a prime number }.
how can i prove or disprove that 
 $\Omega \subset Z \setminus bZ  $ where $Z$ is integer 
 set and $a,b \epsilon Z$

Comment: By $Z - bn$ did you by any chance mean $Z\setminus bZ$?

Comment: And by $Z$ do you mean $\mathbb Z$ or $\textbf Z$?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $\Omega \cap b \mathbb Z \neq \emptyset$.

If $x \in \Omega$, then $ax+b=p$ with $p$ prime and is also in $b\mathbb Z$, then $x=b \cdot k$ for some $k \in \mathbb Z$. but then $b(ak+1)=bk+b=p$ which is a contradiction unless $b=1$ or $ak+1=1$.

If $b=1$, then the result is false, since $\mathbb Z \setminus b \mathbb Z=\emptyset$.

If $ak+1=1$, then $a=0$ or $k=1$. The first is impossible by $gcd$. If $k=0$, then $b$ is prime, which is also okay, and we don't get a contradiction.

So: if $b>1$ and $b$ is not prime, the result is true.